React native Fire base messaging using FCMHTTP V1 notification is not receiving
Using "@react-native-firebase/app": "^20.3.0", "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^20.3.0", in my react native app .
My goal is to send notification in a quite state app when a particular time happens every thing looks fine.
I've my server side api created which i use to call inside the messaging .
I use post man to test notification it works fine i received the dummy  notification and also get the conditional notification what I give to in my app code only when I trigger api from postman.
But when I test the app without post man it doesn't work  I am not getting notification .
Hre is My code which I write in index.js
messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler(async remoteMessage => {
    console.log('Message handled in the background!', remoteMessage);

    const fcmTokeN = await AsyncStorage.getItem('fcmToken')

    const Latitude = await AsyncStorage.getItem('Latitude1')
    const Longitude = await AsyncStorage.getItem('Longitude1')
    const coordinates = new Coordinates(Latitude, Longitude);
    const params = CalculationMethod.MoonsightingCommittee()
    console.log('FCM Token:', fcmTokeN); // Should log the FCM token
    console.log('Latitude:', Latitude); // Should log the latitude
    console.log('Longitude:', Longitude); // Should log the longitude

    const date = new Date()


    const prayerTimes = new PrayerTimes(coordinates, date, params);
    console.log(prayerTimes)

    const dateto = moment(prayerTimes.current).format('h:mm A')
    //console.log(dateto)
    //console.log(time)
    const current = prayerTimes.currentPrayer();
    const time = current === 'fajr' ? moment(prayerTimes.fajr).format('h:mm A') : current === 'dhuhr' ? moment(prayerTimes.dhuhr).format('h:mm A') :
        current === 'asr' ? moment(prayerTimes.asr).format('h:mm A') : current === 'maghrib' ? moment(prayerTimes.maghrib).format('h:mm A') :
        current === 'isha' ? moment(prayerTimes.isha).format('h:mm A') : ''


    if (fcmTokeN) {
        try {


            for (let index = 0; dateto === current; index++) {

                // here dateto will give current time and the variable current will show the time of particular event if it matches for loop will execute        


                const response = await axios.post('https://server/api/send-notification', {
                    token: fcmTokeN,

                    notification: {
                        title: `${current} prayer time starts at :${time}`,
                        body: `QuranSurah ${dateto}`


                    }
                });
                //  return response       
                break
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error sending notification:', error);
        }
    } else {
        console.log('No FCM token found');
    }
});

